# Loosing input values when cloning jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, clone

When I try clone table row where is input with value, it copy but input loose value.  How to clone table row with value.

[Example online](http://jsfiddle.net/ZNvY7/2/)

```
    <table class="table table-bordered table-striped">
      <tr>
        <th>Service</th>
        <th>Price</th>
        <th>Quantity</th>
        <th>&nbsp;</th>
      </tr>

  <tr class="tr_clone">
    <td><input type="text" ></td>
    <td><span class="controls">
      <input value="100000" class="placeholder span2 datepicker" type="text" value="" data-date-format="yyyy-mm-dd">
      </span></td>
    <td><span class="controls">
      <input class="placeholder span2 datepicker" type="text" value="" data-date-format="yyyy-mm-dd">
      </span></td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
</table>
<p><a href="#" class="tr_clone_add">Clone</a></p>

$(function(){
$(".tr_clone_add").live('click', function() {
    var $tr    = $('table').find('.tr_clone').first();
    var $clone = $tr.clone();
    $clone.find(':text').val('');
    $tr.after($clone);
});
});
```

Comment: You know you're explicitly setting the value to an empty string ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to remove `$clone.find(':text').val('');`.use:

```
$(function(){
 $(".tr_clone_add").live('click', function() {
var $tr    = $('table').find('.tr_clone').first();
var $clone = $tr.clone();
$tr.after($clone);
});
});
```

**[Working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/VA5mc/)**

Answer (score 1):

Do a deep copy by specifying the argument to **[`clone()`](http://api.jquery.com/clone/)** as `true`. This will clone the element with the data and any event bindings intact.

```
var $clone = $tr.clone(true);
```

And of course, remove the line where you are resetting all text inputs to `''`